# Reading textfile and creating iterable list fortran 90

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I want to read a textfile using fortran 90. The file has the following structure

```
Num = 3
N X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
1 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 (1.0,2.0,3.0)
2 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 (1.0,2.0)
3 3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 (1.0,2.0)
```

I have two header lines. The first one (Num = 3) is containing information about how many rows I have to read. The second header line contains a numbering as well as the name of the variables (X1, X2, X3, X4 & X5). The first 4 variables (columns X1-X4) are real data type. However, the last datatype is a list. Within fortran I need the variables column-wise. Somehow like that:

```
X1 = [1.0,2.0,3.0]
X2 = [2.0,3.0,4.0]
X3 = ...
X4 = ...
X5 = [(1.0,2.0,3.0),(1.0,2.0),(1.0,2.0)]
```

I hope somebody can help me.

Cheers

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Also, for the last item, Fortran doesn't have intrinsic list type, so you may try to accommodate I on an array or a custom type

Comment: What does it mean you *"need the variables columnwise"*? What do you call *"a list"* in Fortran?

Comment: I think OP meant to transpose the row data into columns for which there is a separate array per column.